# Pesquisar por intervalo de datas

Tags: java, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como criar um consulta para o banco de dados Oracle retornando uma lista dos pedidos de acordo com um intervalo de datas?

Segue o código utilizado atualmente:

```
        if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Escolha uma Opção de Busca!");

        } else if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            RS = stmt.executeQuery("select numped FROM PCPEDC WHERE DATA > '10/01/2014' and numped =  " + BuscaCodigo);
            while (RS.next()) {


                int Num = RS.getInt("numped");

                consulta = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados Encontrado!!!!");
            }

        } else if (opcaoBusca.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
            RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Data FROM PCPEDC WHERE Data BETWEEN " + Dtincial + "AND" + Dtfinal);


            while (RS.next()) {


                int Num = RS.getInt("numped");
```

Comment: Poderia por favor perguntar um pouco melhor? não entendi muito bem.

Comment: `Data` é uma palavra reservada em vários dialetos de SQL. Nunca use isso como nome de um campo. Além disso, poste mais detalhes do código. Como você declara as variáveis?

Comment: O Usuario tem que digitar Data 1 e Data 2 para que eu possa ter os numero de pedido do banco que corresponde aquele periodo

Comment: Como você declara as variáveis? Qual é o tipo de `DataIni`, `DataFim`, `RS` e `stmt`? Você usa um `try-catch` em algum lugar? Dê o código de um método que seja compilável.

Comment: Isso não compila: `int BuscaCodigo = Integer.parseInt(entBusca.getText()); ResultSet RS = null;
int BuscaCodigo = Integer.parseInt(DataIni.getText()); ResultSet RS = null;`. As variáveis estão duplicadas. Além disso, porque você está lendo uma data com `parseInt`?

Answer (score 3):

A primeira coisa que me saltou aos olhos foi a sua query:

```java
"SELECT Data FROM PCPEDC WHERE DATA BETWEEN '10/09/2010'" + DataIni +  "'AND '" + DataFim +"'"
```

Assim, vamos supor que a data inicial seja 01/01/2015 e a final 12/01/2015, sua consulta fica assim:

```sql
SELECT Data FROM PCPEDC WHERE DATA BETWEEN '10/09/2010'01/01/2015'AND '12/01/2015'
```

O que não é uma query bem formada!

Tendo isso em mente, vamos supor que eu arrume a query. Tudo o que você vai precisar é com o `ResultSet` ler o campo:

```java
Date d = RS.getDate("Data");
```

Por fim, não concatene `String`s para montar a sua query. Esta prática é perigosa e possibilita uma falha de segurança muito perigosa conhecida como injeção de SQL. Ao invés disso, utilize parâmetros em seu `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Data FROM PCPEDC WHERE Data BETWEEN ? AND ?");
ps.setDate(1, DataIni);
ps.setDate(2, DataFim);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Por fim, não se esqueça de fechar o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet` dentro de um bloco `finally`.

Comment: Não usar **Data** como nome de campo por ser palavra reservada não é um conselho útil. Você pode usar isso em diversos bancos (MySql, Oracle, MS SQL Server, Firebird...) sem nenhum problema.

Comment: @Caffé Mantenho. Já tive muita dor-de-cabeça com isso e não gostaria que outros sofressem o que já sofri por conta disso. Além disso, o OP não mencionou qual é o banco de dados dele e nem se existe a possibilidade de haver migração.

Comment: Com qual banco de dados você teve dor de cabeça? Talvez seja útil se você informar o banco e o tipo de problema encontrado.

Comment: @Caffé https://www.drupal.org/node/141051 - No padrão SQL 1999, `DATA` é uma palavra reservada. Na época que tive problemas, em 2006, eu estava trabalhando com Oracle, Access, MySQL e PostgreSQL. Era uma ferramenta para múltiplos bancos de dados e teve um deles que deu erro.

Comment: @Caffé Tirei do texto a questão da palavra-chave `Data`.

Comment: @Victor brother ainda não consegui entender esse procedimento. Vou reeditar e te mostrar qual e minha duvida Olha só o codigo que eu postei agora, nesse codigo eu já consigo verificar se o codigo do pedido e valido. Agora eu queria pesquisar por data e pegar o numero de pedido por essa pesquisa.

Comment: Obrigado @Fernando